# Hide caret in textarea

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a Linux style command line to my HTML/CSS site. I made a Span and would like to put a Textarea next to it to simulate the input. But I can't get rid of the blinking caret in the textarea. Does anyone know how I can hide the caret?

I want to do it in HTML/CSS only if it's possible.

```css
#name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5%;
  color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  /*text-align: center;*/
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  font-size: 50pt;
}

blink {
  animation: blink 1.2s infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  40% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  50% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  90% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="name"><span>nicolo@luescher:~$<blink>_</blink></span></div>
```

Comment: EDIT 1: I forgot to add the Textare in the Code-Snippet -.-                       <div id="name"><span>nicolo@luescher:~$<blink>_</blink><textarea></textarea></span></div>

Comment: EDIT 2: I don't mean the mouse cursor. I mean the blinking line in the Textarea. (since I added my own "cursor")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text-shadow` to get it just `tranparent` font color and use `text-shadow` so when you click in `textarea` you will not get `cursor` but still you can write in it.

Below is example i posted

```css
textarea {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px tomato;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

**2020 Answer:**

```
textarea {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

**All modern browsers support!! Chrome 57+, Edge, Firefox 53+, Safari 11.1+**

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color

caniuse: https://caniuse.com/?search=caret-color (94.53% up to 2021-07-28)

```css
textarea{
width:300px;
height:60px;
}


textarea{
caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Type Here">Hello World</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to do this:

```
   textarea:hover{
     cursor: none; 
    }
```

textarea is where you want the cursor to be hidden :)