# Remove the typing indicator from textarea

Tags: html, css

I'm struggeling with removing the blinking indicator that pops up when writing something into my textarea. I've tried matching the color to the background color, but that hid my text as well. Does anyone have a quick fix for this in html/css? Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Or maybe even this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845792/hide-cursor-in-textarea

Comment: So why do you want to hide the cursor? Seems like an odd request.

Comment: Do you want to hide it because you think it looks cooler? Don't do it, this indicator is there for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can colour the caret only instead of the text:

```css
textarea {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this property

```
caret-color: transparent;
```